# flutter Firebase & iOS 15 -Cannot Contact Recaptcha. Check Your Connection and Try Again

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

Today I submitted my app to App Review and I got a message about the Recaptcha not loading.

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

[image]

one possible solution is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown) // Setting this to .unknown is what seems to have helped
}
```

but i don't know how to apply it to flutter.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this issue? I am also facing the same with my flutter app sent for an approval on App Store Connect.

Comment: yes, looking on the internet I found that the error is in Apple's sandbox.
I replied by saying that I have checked both iPhone and iPad simulator and everything was working correctly, and that the problem is in your sandbox.
so they approved me the app.

Comment: That's good to know. Did you enable Apple Push Notifications for your app before sending the app for review? I read in both Apple & firebase documentation that an APN is required to be set in firebase for push notifications to work as it uses Silent APNs notifications for phone verification. I wonder if this has anything to do with reCAPTCHA?

Comment: I'm developing a new app with notifications now, as soon as the public let you know.

Comment: Can you please share the link which you followed on Internet regarding error in Apple's Sandbox? I am still not able to reproduce the issue on my iOS devices/emulators and Apple is rejecting it irrespectively. This would help me to have further discussions with Apple. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to help you, the only thing I can tell you is what I've done.
I replied to Apple that the problem is not present in both the simulator and the physical device. but that second stackoverflow problem is in the apple sandbox. so they accepted me to publish the app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, finally I also got my app approved by Apple. I gave them same explanation and asked them for getting on a technical call to discuss further. They reviewed it again and approved.

Comment: I'm happy for you. good work